# form submiting without validating

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

I'm using jquery to validate a form and php to submit the data to a mySQlite database. The problem that I am facing is that my form will submit even though it is not validating. I have the php file linked in the action attribute of the form. the js file is only linked to the html with $('#signUpForm').validate(...). is there a way to link it to the submit button? Or a way to link it similar to how the php is linked to the action attribute?

Comment: Could you paste more related code?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does it resolve you issue?

Answer (score 0):

specify your validation method(say validateForm) in form tag as `onsubmit  = "return validateForm()"`

Comment: I added "onsubmit = "return validate()"" to my form tag and it did not fix the issue. I used the validation method from the jquery validation plugin. my method is in a seperate file from my form. validation.js.

Comment: is your javascript file referred in a script tag?

Comment: yes it is i may not have placed it in the proper place though
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>

Comment: What is the return value of `validateForm()` it needs to be true or false to continue with the form or stop it, respectively.

Comment: I'm not surethat what the value of validateForm() is. how would i find this. Is there a way I can post all my code? I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following.

```
<form id="frm" name="frm">
    <input type="button" onclick="btnClicked()">
</form>


<script>
    function btnClicked()
    {
       if(validateform())//this function should be write by yourself.
       {
           $('#frm').submit();
       }
    }
</script>
```

Here is jquery submit document. [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)